# What TV show features kids working as secret agents for a group called Alpha Centauri?

Tags: story-identification

When I was around 10 (1993-1994-ish), I remember watching a TV show where kids worked as secret agents, part of an organization called "Alpha Centauri" (or was it just Centauri?). I found their technology extremely fascinating at the time -- laptops, iPhone-like gadgets, secret headquarters hidden in a farm. I remember one episode that involved the Crown Jewels being stolen.

Does anybody remember the name of this show?

*Edit:* They'd usually sign off calls by saying "Centauri Out".

Comment: Yey! Thanks! I've been searching for this Program Title since this morning. I was then 10 when I got hooked into watching this program with my brother. Now that I have kids, I want them to know and watch this "Mission Top Secret"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a [similar question on Yahoo! answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090405105216AAO4WF8). The only answer links to an Australian show called [Mission Top Secret](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112076/). The descriptions seems pretty much like your own.

Comment: Aha!! Now I just gotta find DVDs for it.